# Designing simple todo list data structure for Firebase DB

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am in process of learning to create an app using firebase. The idea is to have simple Todo list.

My structure needs to address items needed by a user.

Is this the right approach ?

```
{
"todo": [{
    "items": [{
        "userid": "123",
        "item": "Milk"
    }, {
        "userid": "123",
        "item": "Butter"
    }, {
        "userid": "456",
        "item": "Bread"
        }]
  }]
}
```

So to show all items for a user 123 I can just use userid as filter. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes can do this:

```
Users
  useruid 
    name:userx
    email:userx@gmail.co
  useruid
    name:usery
    email:usery@gmail.com

items
  randomid
     useruid: idofuserx
     item:food
  randomid
     useruid:idofusery
     item:foods
```

The useruid will be the id of each user that was added in the `users` node.

To get items of userx:

```
let query = DBref?.queryOrdered(byChild:"useruid").queryEqual(toValue: idofuserx)
```

Comment: Thank you , that looks really good and I will accept this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can try this approach. I feel this is more optimistic. Here the duplication of items will be resolved.

You can have 2 objects

1. `User`
2. `Item`

in `User` object you can save `itemId` and details about the user (eg: name, emailId, address) and in `Item` you will have details regarding that(eg: name, category, ...) Which looks something like this:

```
User
   userId1
       name: abc
       emailId: abc@some.com
       address: abc, some address
       itemId: itemId1
   userId2
       name: acd
       emailId: acd@some.com
       address: acd, some address
       itemId: itemId2

Item
   itemId1
       name: Milk
       category: some category
   itemId2
       name: Bread
       category: some category
   itemId3
       name: Butter
       category: some category
```

Comment: this does not work. The itemid and the userid cannot have values since they are nodes that contain `key:values`. Also if you mean the itemid/userids.. does not have a value then itemid cannot be added under user without a value

Comment: What I mean was, itemId will be the key and the object under it will be the value for it. I have updated the pojo.

Comment: your also doing a `join` here which is not recommended. It is better to duplicate, https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html

Comment: From the link you have mentioned- `Duplicating data like this can be counter-intuitive to many developers. However, in order to build truly scalable applications, denormalization is almost a requirement.` and it is also told that if you are duplicating the data then you have to think about deletion/ modification of data too. I prefer saving `itemId` instead of whole object. Its based on developer how he will use it in front end. And thanks for the suggestion.